# Indefinite Integral Inverse Trigonometric Function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{2}{9w^2+25}dw$$
I already know this will be equal to $\frac{1}{a} \arctan(x/a)$,
but I don't know how to factor out the $9$. I only know how to take out the $2$.

Comment: Then start by dividing both numerator and denominator by 9.  You'll have fractions, but it will be that $A/(w^2 + B^2)$ form you're looking for.

Comment: I like using $w=\frac53u$. Then you get a constant multiple of $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}$

Answer (score 3):

Well you can easily reduce the integrand to $2/9 \cdot \frac{1}{w^2+(5/3)^2}$ or possibly $2/25 \cdot \frac{1}{(3w/5)^2+1}$. What does this tell you?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}} 2\int \frac{dw}{9w^2+25} = 2\int\frac{dw}{25(\frac{9}{25} w^2 + 1)} = \frac{2}{25}\int\frac{dw}{\left(\frac35 w\right)^2 + 1} \\[12pt]
& = \frac{2}{3\cdot5} \int \frac{\frac35\, dw}{\left(\frac35 w\right)^2 + 1} = \frac{2}{15} \int \frac{du}{u^2+1}\text{ etc.}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Pretty close to my hint :-) +1

Comment: You're a bit more generous than I am. Pretty much gave it away.

Comment: I think if something is not obvious to those who've never seen it but is nonetheless wholly routine, then giving away one instance before expecting them to do others is not unreasonable.